# how to get the counted value

Tags: php

how can i get the result from my query COUNT.

this is how it looks of my query in my database

```
   fname  lname   mname    positionName  COUNT(tbl_votes.studId)
    jr    gwapo   is-very    chairman           2
```

and this is how my webpage looks

```
       Name           Position      Number of Votes
  jr is-very gwapo    chairman         ______
```

and heres my code.

```
<?php
  if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT tbl_student.fname, tbl_student.lname, tbl_student.mname, tbl_position.positionName, Count(tbl_votes.studId) FROM tbl_candidate Inner Join tbl_student ON tbl_candidate.studId = tbl_student.studId Inner Join tbl_position ON tbl_candidate.positionId = tbl_position.positionId Inner Join tbl_votes ON tbl_student.studId = tbl_votes.candId WHERE tbl_position.positionId =  '1' GROUP BY tbl_student.fname, tbl_student.lname, tbl_student.mname, tbl_position.positionName")) {

      if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
          echo "<table border='1' cellpadding='10'>";
          // set table headers
          echo "<tr><th>Name</th><th>Position</th><th>Number of Votes</th></tr>";

          while ($row = $result->fetch_object()) {
              echo "<tr>";
              echo "<td>" . $row->fname . " " . $row->mname . " " . $row->lname . " </td>";
              echo "<td>" . $row->positionName . "</td>";
              //this is where i suppose to echo the count result
            echo "<td>" . $row-> ??? . "</td>"; 
            echo"<tr>";
          }
          echo "</table>";
      } else {
          echo "No results to display!";
      }

  }
  $mysqli->close();

?>
```

heres my problem, how could i pass the "Count(tbl_votes.studId)" in 
"echo "" . $row-> ??? . ""; " ? pls help...

Comment: @VladPreda thanks a lot for fixing the indentation in the question.

Comment: No problem. I recommend you use an IDE that does this automatically. I just copied it there and copied it back :)

Comment: to all.. thnks for responding...

Answer (score 1):

In sql query, change `Count(tbl_votes.studId)` to `Count(tbl_votes.studId) as stu_count`.

And in php, you can use `$row->stu_count`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an [**SQL alias**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/problems-with-alias.html).

```
Count(tbl_votes.studId) as cnt
//or
Count(tbl_votes.studId) 'cnt'
```

Then you can access it with `$row->cnt`

Some rules about aliases:

- you can use an alias in the rest of your query (in your example you could use `ORDER BY cnt`). *Note: as far as I know you can't use an alias you created in the select in another select statement.* For example, `SELECT COUNT(something) AS cnt, cnt+3 FROM` ... will not work
- you can use alias for tables, and replace the table name with the alias in future usages

Answer (score 0):

Try
    Select field1, field2, Count(tbl_votes.studId) as cnt from ...

Answer (score 0):

instead of writing

```
count(some_field)
```

write

```
count(some_field) as count_some_field
```

You give alias to that count field. You can access it as $row->count_some_field.

Answer (score 0):

you should use '**as**' with '**count**' . So you query will become like this

```
"SELECT tbl_student.fname, tbl_student.lname, tbl_student.mname, tbl_position.positionName, Count(tbl_votes.studId) as no_of_votes FROM tbl_candidate Inner Join tbl_student ON tbl_candidate.studId = tbl_student.studId Inner Join tbl_position ON tbl_candidate.positionId = tbl_position.positionId Inner Join tbl_votes ON tbl_student.studId = tbl_votes.candId WHERE tbl_position.positionId =  '1' GROUP BY tbl_student.fname, tbl_student.lname, tbl_student.mname, tbl_position.positionName"
```

then you can get it via php as

`$row->no_of_vote`

for mor information see [COUNT AS](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_count.asp)